# Why radiobutton is not getting read from gridview while looping?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, c#-4.0

I have a gridview and it has radio button. I have button outside grid. I want to loop through grid and pick value of radio button if selected.

I have done this but it doesn't work for checked radio button.

```
 protected void btnCheckOut_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                foreach (GridViewRow row in gvBooks.Rows)
                {
                    if (((RadioButton)row.FindControl("rdSelect")).Checked)
                    {
                        Utilities.Utilities.setPageMessage("checked", Utilities.Utilities.severity.error, Page.Master);
                        return;
                    }
                }}
```

aspx:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvBooks" runat="server" DataKeyNames="BookID"
                    AutoGenerateColumns="false" EmptyDataText="No Data Found">
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Select">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                 <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hdnBookID" ClientIDMode="AutoID" Value='<%# Eval("BookID") %>' />
                                <asp:RadioButton runat="server" ID="rdSelect"/>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Title" HeaderText="Book Title" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="ISBN" HeaderText="ISBN" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="PublishYear" HeaderText="Publish Year" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="CoverPrice" HeaderText="Cover Price" />
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Status">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="lableCheckOutStatus" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("CheckOutStatusDescription") %>' />
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>

                    </Columns>
                </asp:GridView>

 <asp:Button ID="btnCheckOut" CssClass="button" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" Text="Check Out" OnClick="btnCheckOut_Click" />
```

Comment: _"It doesn't work"_ means _what_? Show your aspx page

Comment: it bypasses the if condition even the radio button is checked

Comment: Are they generated dynamically or declared on the aspx? Show it

Comment: @Rango: check updated code